# Passing messages between two processes

Tags: c++, node.js, process, raspberry-pi, ipc

I'm building a system that has 2 processes.

**Process 1**
This process is actually a `Node.js` program. This process is actually a Web Server handling the incoming request.

**Process 2**
This process is actually a `C++` program.

Both the processes are started automatically at startup with help of `rc.local`

Now, for `Process 1` there are some specific request that should be passed to `Process 2`.

For example, if `Process 1` receives a post request at route `/enqueue` with a `JSON` body payload, `Process 1` should stringify the `JSON` and pass to `Process 2`.

When `Process 2` receives the `JSON`, it should kill a worker thread and start a new thread with that `JSON` to perform the actual task. The worker thread should be killed irrespective of whether the worker thread is still processing previous `JSON`

If both the processes were `Node.js` application, I could have forked `Process 2` from `Process 1` and used the following code.

```
process.on('message',function(message){
    //implementation
}
...
process.send(data);
```

But my second process is a `C++` app.

Any idea on how to implement it?

**Note:** Before flagging this question, please keep in mind I'm not looking for a full code. I just need the idea on how to do it.

Comment: Take a look at MPI (for example, OpenMPI) via the FFI

Comment: Could you use domain TCP socket to transform messge, then parse and work in your cpp process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the Nodejs messaging/eventing facility for this purpose as it is specific to Node.

You will need to use the communications facilities of your operating system such as Unix, TCP, UDP sockets or an eventing system that both processes can communicate with, like Redis or ZeroMQ.

Comment: Just checked the ZeroMQ. Seems really promising. Will give it a try ASAP